# asp.net membership controls, Login1_LoggingOut is not called when clicking logout

Tags: authentication, asp.net-membership

I have a loging control that is nested within a loginview.  When I click the logout link, my method `

```
protected void LoginStatus1_LoggingOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Guid guidUserId = AuthenticatedUser.LoginUserID;
            if (guidUserId != new Guid())
            {
                PortalDataContext db = new PortalDataContext(AuthenticatedUser.ConnectionString);
                var user = AuthenticatedUser.GetUser(guidUserId);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    user.LastActivityDate = user.LastActivityDate.AddMinutes(-16);

                    db.SubmitChanges();
                }
            }
        }
```

`
is never called.  I think it has something to do with the nesting of the control within a login view.  How can I get around this so I can update the database?  I need to reset the users last activity window to 16 minutes ago so I can tell if the user is still in the system and inactive or if they have logged out completely.

Comment: Can you show us the declarative markup for the LoginStatus control? There is a property you can set that has it render as a hyperlink rather than a LinkButton - in that case, there is no postback when a user logs out.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this and it worked for me.  Are you sure your event is wired up?

```
    <asp:LoginView runat="server">
        <LoggedInTemplate>
            <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" 
                LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutPageUrl="Login.aspx"  OnLoggingOut="LoginStatus1_LoggingOut" />
        </LoggedInTemplate>
    </asp:LoginView>
```